# Showing equivalence of Two definitions for separable extensions

Tags: field-theory, definition, separable-extension

> **Definition $1$:**
>  A polynomial over $F$ is called ***separable*** if it has no multiple roots (i.e., all its roots are distinct).
>   **Definition $2$:**
>  An irreducible polynomial $f(x)\in F[x]$ is ***separable*** over $F$ if $f$ has no repeated roots in any *splitting field*.

*Questions*:
$(a)$ What is the meaning of $S=\{f_i(x):f_i(x)\in F[x]\enspace \forall 1\leq i\leq n\}$ to be separable over $F$ according to the definition #$2$ ?$($ $S$ is not a *multi-set*$)$.
$(b)$ Is definition #$1$ weaker than #$2$ ? If not, Show the equivalence.

*Few Comments*:
For part $(b)$, I guess, they are not equivalent. Reason: Definition #$2$ requires the extension to be splitting field whereas #$1$ can have any extension in which the polynomial splits.
Moreover, I can make a sense of $S$ to be separable over $F$ according to the definition #$1$ but it doesn't make sense in definition #$2$ because the splitting field for each polynomial in $S$ is different.

Comment: Definition 1 should say if it has no multiple roots in (a splitting field/any extension field/an algebraic closure of $F$)

Comment: And yes definition 1 is more general because it doesn't require the polynomial to be irreducible.

Comment: Otherwise, you should specify what it means in definition 1 for a polynomial not to have multiple roots.

Comment: @jgon I have copied the definition #$1$ from *Dummit and Foote, Abstract Algebra* Page $546$.  So, I have no comments about that.

Comment: I realized based on your later comment that it means no multiple roots in any extension of $F$ in which $f$ splits.

Comment: Did you come up with these questions yourself or are they an exercise someone gave you?  As written, part (a) is completely meaningless since the definitions apply to individual polynomials, not to sets of polynomials.

Comment: @EricWofsey These are my questions. I was proving a lemma 4.3(Part 3) from GTM Fields and Galois by Patrick Morandi. I stumbled upon it. So, these were reasonable questions that came to my mind.

Comment: @Kumar The person you appear to be replying to is Eric Wofsey, not me. Though I agree that question (a) doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first definition is nonsense. The polynomial $X^p-t$ over $F(t)$, $t$ an indeterminate over the $p$-element field $F$, has no roots at all in $F(t)$, and according to definition 1 it would be separable.

Actually a polynomial is called *separable* if its irreducible factors are according to definition 2. For instance, $(X-1)^2$ is separable.

Note that having multiple roots in *any* splitting field can be checked in the field where the polynomial is defined in, so the choice of the splitting field is irrelevant.

**Theorem.** *Let $F$ be a field and $f\in F[X]$ a polynomial. There exists an extension field $K$ of $F$ where $f$ has multiple roots if and only if $f$ has a non trivial common factor with its derivative polynomial $f’$.*

Comment: Your theorem has ambiguity. Moreover, I don't understand your third paragraph and the first definition is from Dummit and Foote, Abstract Algebra, Page $546$.

Comment: @Kumar I don't know Dummit and Foote; if that's the definition, it's meaningless, unless they state that “having multiple roots” means also “in some extension field”. Maybe the new form of the theorem is better? Anyway, rather than in D&F, you should look at the definition of separable in the book of Morandi.

Comment: It should be a non-constant polynomial rather than any polynomial because roots don't make sense for the constant polynomials. Moreover, Definition #$2$ is from Morandi, also your theorem is a restatement of Proposition 4.5 from Morandi

Comment: @Kumar A nontrivial common factor means a noninvertible polynomial. The gcd of a constant polynomial with its derivative is the polynomial itself, which is trivial if the polynomial is nonzero. So also constant polynomials satisfy the theorem. A nonzero constant polynomial has zero roots and no multiple one in any extension field; the zero polynomial has every element of the field as a multiple root.